# HttpResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, endpoints

For weeks I've been using the Google App Engine plugin for eclipse to "Generate Cloud Endpoint Client Library" and it worked great. Today, it completely stopped working and responded with "An error occurred while attempting to generate the client libraries. See the error log for more details". The error log indicated a "HttpResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error".

This is happening on code that I haven't touched for weeks and that worked yesterday, in Eclipse and Windows Environments that haven't had any updates whatsoever.

I've tried on three computers-one of which was a completely new install of Eclipse and GAE Plugin For Eclipse. Then, I read through StackOverflow and it seems this problem creeps up occasionally on Google's side. So, is there another problem on Google's side? If so, please fix it soon.

Also, is there any future plan to provide a local plugin that would allow developers to generate the code locally? Or, is there a site that shows the status of the component that seems to be broken on Google's side?

Thanks

### Computer Info:

```
Windows 8.1 x64
Eclipse Luna (4.3)
GAE Plugin For Eclipse (3.8.0v201410302155-rel-r42)
App Engine SDK 1.9.19 and 1.8.8 (I tried both independently)
```

Eclipse Error Info..........

### MESSAGE:

```
Unexpected Exception
```

### EXCEPTION STACK TRACE:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction$1.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmGenerationException: com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createClientLibFromApiConfig(SwarmApiCreator.java:201)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createSwarmApi(SwarmApiCreator.java:320)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmServiceCreator.create(SwarmServiceCreator.java:444)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction$1.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:80)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1054)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.CloudClientLibGenerator.postRequest(CloudClientLibGenerator.java:53)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.CloudClientLibGenerator.generateClientLib(CloudClientLibGenerator.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at     com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createCli    entLibFromApiConfig(SwarmApiCreator.java:199)
    ... 4 more
```

### SESSION DATA:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.4.2.M20150204-1700
java.version=1.8.0_05
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct -clean
```

I've launched a bug report with google at:
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log&groupby=&sort=&id=12150

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has responded with the following workaround solution:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/endpoints_tool#generating_a_client_library_bundle_from_a_backend_api

In short, assume:

- Windows OS
- Eclipse (any version)
- Maven output (replace maven with gradle if that's your taste)
- Appengine SDK 1.9.19 (though others should work)
- Your WEB-INF folder is located at c:\myproject\war
- Your EndPoint API contains com.myproject.MyApiClass and com.myproject.MyApiClass2
- You'd like to output the client libraries to c:\

Then you can generate the client libraries locally by doing the following:

1. Run a Command Prompt "**As Administrator**"
2. In the command prompt,change to the directory with your appengine-java-sdk

   cd C:\Eclipse\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.19\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.19\bin
3. Generate the libraries

   enpoints.cmd get-client-lib --war=c:\myproject\war --build-system=maven --output=c:\ com.myproject.MyApiClass com.myproject.MyApiClass2

Notice that output to c:\ requires the Command Prompt be run as administrator and that the two classes in the API are separated by spaces.

Also, if you did not supply an output, the client library zip files are located in the same directory that you executed the command prompt from (C:\Eclipse\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.19\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.19\bin if you followed the instructions exactly)

Comment: I tried the below for android client, gives me error

> endpoints.cmd get-client-lib --war=D:\MyProj-AppEngine\war -bs gradle com.myproj.QuizTableEndpoint.class



I get the below message

> endpoints.cmd get-client-lib --war=D:\MyProj-AppEngine\war -bs gradle com.myproj.QuizTableEndpoint.class

Comment: First of all, what is the path to your WEB-INF folder?

Comment: Actually, I see a problem. Replace com.myproj.QuizTableEndpoint.class with com.myproj.QuizTableEndpoint (ie remove .class)

Comment: that helped, thanks. Now it says API client library written to .\quiztableendpoint-v1-java.zip. Where can I find this zip file?